# Shortest Path, Least Turns Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

There is a square grid *with obstacles*. On that grid, there are two members of a class `Person`. They face a certain direction (up, right, left or down). Each person has a certain amount of energy. Making the persons turn or making them move consumes energy (turning consumes 1 energy unit, moving consumes 5 energy units).

My goal is to make them move as close as possible next to each other (expressed as the manhattan distance), consuming the least amount of energy possible. Keep in mind there are obstacles on the grid.

How would I do this?

Comment: `as close as possible next to each other` - should the distance between them account for obstacles, or should the absolute distance be minimal? What I mean, is it your task to minimize the resulting (after the movement) `x1-x2+y1-y2` or to minimize the resulting (after the movement) `pathfind().length` distance? I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: The manhattan distance `abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)` should be as small as possible in the end, not taking into account obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a breadth-first search and count a minimal energy value to reach each square. It would terminate when the players meet or there is no more energy left.

Comment: There can be a case when after 1 step there's only 1 wall separating you (distance = 1), but if you use up all your energy, say 20 steps, the distance will become 10 (walking around huge obstacle).

Comment: I guess it will be needed to spend all energy or explore whole maze to see all possible positions. So I will keep track of the best solution during the algorithm and update it if situation changes.

Comment: Yes, I believe Dijkstra is needed here, but I'm not sure how to take turning into account.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make assumptions and remove them later.

Assuming the grid is smaller than 1000x1000 and that you can't run out of energy..:

Assuming they can't reach each other:
for Person1,Person2, find their respective sets of reachable points, R1,R2.

(use Breadth first search for example)

sort R1 and R2 by x value.

Now go through R1 and R2 to find the pair of points that are closest together.
hint: we sorted the two arrays so we know when points are close in terms of their x coordinate. We never have to go further apart on the x coordinate than the current found minimum.

Assuming they can reach each other: Use BFS from person1 until you find person2 and record the path

If the path found using BFS required no turns, then that is the solution,

Otherwise:

**Create 4 copies of the grid (call them right-grid, left-grid, up-grid, down-grid).**

the rule is, you can only be in the left grid if you are moving left, you can only be in the right grid if you are moving right, etc. To turn, you must move from one grid to the other (which uses energy).

Create this structure and then use BFS.

Example:

Now the left grid assumes you are moving left, so create a graph from the left grid where every point is connected to the point on its left with the amount of energy to move forwards.

The only other option when in the left-grid is the move to the up-grid or the down-grid (which uses 1 energy), so connect the corresponding gridpoints from up-grid and left-grid etc.

Now you have built your graph, simply use breadth first search again.

I suggest you use pythons NetworkX, it will only be about 20 lines of code.

Make sure you don't connect squares if there is an obstacle in the way.

good luck.